# How to pass "this" into a function

Tags: javascript

I'm doing something simple in vanilla JavaScript but it stumps me.

Here is my HTML and JavaScript code:

```
<div id="slide" class="slide-modal">
    
        <div class="status-div">
            <div>10:25 Optimization requested</div>
            <div onclick="this.parentNode.style.display='none'"><img src="assets/images/cross.svg" /></div>
        </div>

        <div class="status-div">
            <div>10:26 Optimization successfully completed</div>
            <div onclick="this.parentNode.style.display='none'"><img src="assets/images/cross.svg" /></div>
        </div>

        <div class="status-div">
            <div>10:30 Booking requested</div>
            <div onclick="this.parentNode.style.display='none'"><img src="assets/images/cross.svg" /></div>
        </div>

        <div class="status-div">
            <div>10:45 Booking requested</div>
            <div onclick="this.parentNode.style.display='none'"><img src="assets/images/cross.svg" /></div>
        </div>

        <div class="status-div">
            <div>11:00 Booking requested</div>
            <div onclick="this.parentNode.style.display='none'"><img src="assets/images/cross.svg" /></div>
        </div>

        <div class="status-div">
            <div>11:30 Booking requested</div>
            <div onclick="this.parentNode.style.display='none'"><img src="assets/images/cross.svg" /></div>
    </div>

<script>

function closeStatus() {
            this.parentNode.style.display='none';
            const allNotifications = document.querySelectorAll(".status-div");
            if(allNotifications.length == 0 ) {
                document.getElementById('slide').style.visibility='hidden'; 
            }
        }
</script>
```

What I want to do is to use the closeStatus() function to run on the onclick here

```
 <div onclick="this.parentNode.style.display='none'"><img src="assets/images/cross.svg" /></div>
```

to close the parent "status-div". But how do I pass the "this"?

So it would be:

```
 <div onclick="closeStatus"><img src="assets/images/cross.svg" /></div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)? Alternatively, you might be able to use [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) instead of `this` within your event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you assign the event listener (onclick) You may need to pass `this`. `this` is the DOM element that invoked the event listener.

The first argument to an event handler, is the actual event itself, which will have a reference to the DOM element that generated the event.

If you want to pass the DOM element, you can do this `<div onclick="closeStatus(this)"><img src="assets/images/cross.svg" /></div>`

Update your `closeStatus` method to expect the element:

```
function closeStatus(elm) {
            elm.parentNode.style.display='none';
            const allNotifications = document.querySelectorAll(".status-div");
            if(allNotifications.length == 0 ) {
                document.getElementById('slide').style.visibility='hidden'; 
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you please show me an example of how "this" would be recognized in the function? If I do "closeStatus(this)" it doesn't work.

Comment: Update your closeStatus to use the passed in element, and not `this`

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked. It's been years since I did something like this!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the *event* instead of trying to use this:

```
function closeStatus(e) {
    e.target.parentNode.style.display='none';
    const allNotifications = document.querySelectorAll(".status-div");
    if(allNotifications.length == 0 ) {
        document.getElementById('slide').style.visibility='hidden'; 
    }
}
```

Now make sure you pass the event with the keyword *event* in your onclick:

`<div onclick="closeStatus(event)"></div>`

And as you can see, the event (called e in the function) has a property called target, which is your div.

Answer (score 0):

I've just rearranged your code. I think it works and also cleanup the HTML.

```
<div id="slide" class="slide-modal">

    <div class="status-div">
        <div>10:25 Optimization requested for +GE-2103 2106</div>
        <img src="assets/images/cross.svg" class="close" />
    </div>

    <div class="status-div">
        <div>10:26 Optimization for +GE-2103 2106 successfully completed</div>
         <img src="assets/images/cross.svg" class="close" />
    </div>

    <div class="status-div">
        <div>10:30 Booking requested for +GE-2103 2106 requested</div>
         <img src="assets/images/cross.svg" class="close" />
    </div>

    <div class="status-div">
        <div>10:45 Booking requested for +GE-2103 2106 requested</div>
         <img src="assets/images/cross.svg" class="close" />
    </div>

    <div class="status-div">
        <div>11:00 Booking requested for +GE-2103 2106 requested</div>
        <img src="assets/images/cross.svg" class="close" />
    </div>

    <div class="status-div">
        <div>11:30 Booking requested for +GE-2103 2106 requested</div>
        <img src="assets/images/cross.svg" class="close" />
</div>

<script>

    var close_btns = document.querySelectorAll('img.close');

    close_btns.forEach(close_btn => {
        close_btn.addEventListener("click", function closeStatus(event) {
           
            event.target.parentNode.style.display='none';
            
            const allNotifications = document.querySelectorAll(".status-div");
          
            if(allNotifications.length == 0 ) {
               document.getElementById('slide').style.visibility='hidden'; 
            }
        });
    });
    
</script>
```